# South African passport holder traveling via Heathow to Ireland

Tags: visas, uk, layovers, south-african-citizens

My daughter is traveling from SA to Ireland Dublin via Heathrow .  She will be catching a connecting flight to Dublin via an Irish airline 
What visa is required ?

Comment: I have just edited the linked duplicate question to list the full conditions for transit without visa.  Holders of a biometric visa for the Republic of Ireland who have an onward flight ticket to that country are eligible.

Answer (score 0):

Transit visas are for South Africans who are not going to stay in the UK for longer than 48 hours. This generally is applicable to South Africans that intend on stopping over or changing flights in the UK on route to another destination.

There are 3 main types Transit visas:

1: Direct Airside Transit
2: Visitor in Transit
3: General Visitor Visa

1: Direct Airside Transit visa (DATV)

This visa is applicable for South Africans stopping over to connect with other flights. There is a 24 hour restriction on this visa and it does not allow South Africans to pass through the UK Border Control.

The DATV is perfect for South Africans stopping over in the UK on route to Europe.

Fortunately this DATV visa has an exemption clause that allows for South Africans with valid visas and connecting flights to the certain destinations to be exempt from applying for this visa. The visas and connected flights needed in order to qualify for the exemption are: 
-   Australia
-   Canada
-   New Zealand
-   USA

Therefore South Africans who have valid visas and flights on route to the above mentioned countries can stop over and change flights without needing visas. This exemption is known as "Transit without Visa". Please note that this also includes return flights to South Africa.

2: Visitor in Transit

This visa is designed for those who have to catch connecting flights at different airports. It has a 48 hour restriction. Therefore this visa category grants permission for South Africans to pass through UK borders for no more than 48 hours.

This visa suits South Africans arriving at Heathrow and that have to catch a connecting flight that departs from Gatwick for example.

3: General Visitor Visas

This visa grants permission for South Africans to pass through the UK borders for at least 48 hours. Entering the UK as a General visitor has employment restrictions and well as a maximum period of applicants to remain in the UK for 6 months. Take a look at our Visitor Visa page for more information.

Comment: You have missed several qualifying conditions for the "transit without visa" program.  Holders of a biometric visa for Ireland are also exempted.